# Suppose $|x_n-x_k|\le n/k^2$ for all $n$ and $k$. Show that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $|x_n-x_k|\le n/k^2$ for all $n$ and $k$. Show that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy.

Attempt: Find $M\in N$ s.t. for $n,k\ge M, n/k^2<\varepsilon \hspace{0.5cm}\forall\varepsilon>0.$

For given $\varepsilon$, let $M>1/\sqrt \varepsilon.$ Then, for $n,k\ge M$ $$|n/k^2|\le n/M^2<n\varepsilon.$$

I don't know how to deal with $n$ here. Could you give some hint?

Comment: *Find $M\in N$ s.t. for $n,k\ge M, n/k^2<\varepsilon \hspace{0.5cm}\forall\varepsilon>0.$* This is bound to fail since $\lim_{n\to \infty}n/k^2=\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Replace $k$ with $n+k$ to get the proper left-hand side of a Cauchy-like inequality.

Comment: For $n,k\ge M, |x_n-x_{n+k}|\le n/(n+k)^2\le n/M^2$. I think we still cannot eliminate $n$ on the numerator. Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @SihyunKim For $n$ large enough, the right-hand side is smaller than a fixed $\varepsilon$, *no matter what $k\geq0$ is*. This is the definition of $x_n$ being Cauchy. It relies on the fact that $\frac{n}{(n+k)^2}\leq\frac1n$ for all $n$ and all $k\geq 0$.

Comment: Can we justify replacing $k$ with $n+k$?

Comment: @SihyunKim Yes, if something is true for ALL $k$, it means you can replace $k$ with a box and write whatever you like in the box.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood correctly (what i doubt). Let's make $n$ constant.
$$|x_n-x_k|\leq\frac{n}{k^2}$$
Holds for all $k$, so we can take a limit with both sides as $k\to \infty$. We get by the squezee theorem that $$\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} x_k = x_n$$
So the sequenence is convergent, so it's Cauchy

Comment: So the sequence has to be constant since its limit is equal to any of its terms. Neat. Note that it was not too hard to prove directly that it's Cauchy by replacing $k$ with $n+k$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_k|x_n-x_k| < +\infty$

Thus $$\lim_{k \to + \infty}|x_n-x_k| \to 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n,k \to + \infty}|x_n-x_k|=0$$

So $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Since $n \ge M$, you can say $\frac{n}{M^2} \le \frac{M}{M^2} = \frac1M$. So define $M > \frac1{\varepsilon}$ instead of $M > \frac1{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$.